# Withdrawing UK visa application

Tags: visas, uk, long-term

Has anyone withdrawn the UK visa application (United States)? Typically how many days does it take for the passport to return from the embassy? Apparently, UKVI helpdesk is not providing me the expected date.

Answer (score 3):

My fiancee withdrew her application originally for a UK visit visa and received her passport back within about two weeks from the embassy. They did not consider her application whatsoever.

She applied about three weeks after a refusal attempting to enter the UK. She withdrew because her situation had not changed, and instead waited about five months before applying once more - to which she was granted a visa.

She applied from the USA also, from the embassy in New York.